# How do I set cell value to Date and apply default Excel date format?

Tags: java, date, apache-poi

I've been using Apache POI for some time to read existing Excel 2003 files programmatically. Now I have a new requirement to create entire .xls files in-memory (still using Apache POI) and then write them to a file at the end. The only problem standing in my way is the handling of cells with dates.

Consider the following code:

```
Date myDate = new Date();
HSSFCell myCell;
// code that assigns a cell from an HSSFSheet to 'myCell' would go here...
myCell.setCellValue(myDate);
```

When I write the workbook containing this cell out to a file and open it with Excel, the cell is displayed as a number. Yes, I do realize that Excel stores its 'dates' as the number of days since January 1 1900 and that is what the number in the cell represents.

**QUESTION: What API calls can I use in POI to tell it that I want a default date format applied to my date cell?**

Ideally I want the spreadsheet cell to be displayed with the same default date format that Excel would have assigned it if a user had manually opened the spreadsheet in Excel and typed in a cell value that Excel recognized as being a date.

Answer (score 220, accepted):

http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CreateDateCells

```
CellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
CreationHelper createHelper = wb.getCreationHelper();
cellStyle.setDataFormat(
    createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("m/d/yy h:mm"));
cell = row.createCell(1);
cell.setCellValue(new Date());
cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
```

Comment: Thanks ninja, this works for me. One comment for others who need to do this. There is a POI class named `BuiltinFormats` that lists out all the standard formats (not just date formats) that Excel knows. I'm sticking with one of those to use as my parameter to the `getFormat()` method shown in the snippet above.

Comment: The important part is in the comments of the link: we style the second cell as a date (and time).  It is important to create a new cell style from the workbook otherwise you can end up modifying the built in style and effecting not only this cell but other cells.

Comment: Thanks, @ninja.  Do you know why `getCreationHelper()` is needed?  I'm working with Mule right now to generate an Excel output file and I was actually able to use the `createDataFormat()` without the creation helper and generated an Excel file in my test.  Is there a downside to not using it?  Thanks!

Comment: @Rashiki This answer was posted 6 years ago. I guess that the API of the Apache POI has changed during this time. My answer to your question is 'No, there is no downside (if it works as expected)'

Comment: I don't see any format for `mm/dd/yyyy`. When I use any other format, the excel displays an error `File error, some number formats may have been lost`, it does display `Date` type in excel. I have no clue how this can be fixed.

Comment: This example contains a dateTime format example not a date only example.

Comment: This is looking good and works, but it does not set cell type to "Date", it is "Custom".

Comment: @DmitriyPopov You're right. I'm getting #### as end result. Anyway to fix it?

Answer (score 31):

To set to default Excel type Date (defaulted to OS level locale /-> i.e. xlsx will look different when opened by a German or British person/ and flagged with an asterisk if you choose it in Excel's cell format chooser) you should:

```
    CellStyle cellStyle = xssfWorkbook.createCellStyle();
    cellStyle.setDataFormat((short)14);
    cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
```

I did it with xlsx and it worked fine.

Comment: Absolutely agreed on fiffy's comment. I have only one question. What is the best approach. Rely on the dataFormat short value (14) or the string value ("m/d/yy"). Which is really the constant value which describes the standard date format in Excel? DataFormat.getFormat() has both with string and with short value as parameter.

Comment: Miklos, i do not know how does  the string value solution work. I would be glad if somebody could feedback whether that is also showing the "language 
 based different default date format" in Excels with different languages, too.

Answer (score 15):

This example is for working with .xlsx file types. This example comes from a .jsp page used to create a .xslx spreadsheet.

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*; //import needed

XSSFWorkbook  wb = new XSSFWorkbook ();  // Create workbook
XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet();      // Create spreadsheet in workbook
XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(rowIndex); // Create the row in the spreadsheet


//1. Create the date cell style
XSSFCreationHelper createHelper = wb.getCreationHelper();
XSSFCellStyle cellStyle         = wb.createCellStyle();
cellStyle.setDataFormat(
createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy")); 

//2. Apply the Date cell style to a cell

//This example sets the first cell in the row using the date cell style
cell = row.createCell(0);
cell.setCellValue(new Date());
cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
```

Answer (score 5):

In addition to @BlondeCode [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794659/how-do-i-set-cell-value-to-date-and-apply-default-excel-date-format/41124537#41124537), here are the list of all available formats that you can get with
`creationHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat((short) index)`

0 = "General"
1 = "0"
2 = "0.00"
3 = "#,##0"
4 = "#,##0.00"
5 = ""$"#,##0_);("$"#,##0)"
6 = ""$"#,##0_);Red"
7 = ""$"#,##0.00_);("$"#,##0.00)"
8 = ""$"#,##0.00_);Red"
9 = "0%"
10 = "0.00%"
11 = "0.00E+00"
12 = "# ?/?"
13 = "# ??/??"
14 = "m/d/yy"
15 = "d-mmm-yy"
16 = "d-mmm"
17 = "mmm-yy"
18 = "h:mm AM/PM"
19 = "h:mm:ss AM/PM"
20 = "h:mm"
21 = "h:mm:ss"
22 = "m/d/yy h:mm"
23-36 = reserved
37 = "#,##0_);(#,##0)"
38 = "#,##0_);Red"
39 = "#,##0.00_);(#,##0.00)"
40 = "#,##0.00_);Red"
41 = "*(* #,##0*);*(* (#,##0);*(* "-"*);*(@*)"

42 = "*("$"* #,##0_);*("$"* (#,##0);*("$"* "-"*);*(@*)"

43 = "*(* #,##0.00_);*(* (#,##0.00);*(* "-"??*);*(@*)"

44 = "*("$"* #,##0.00_);*("$"* (#,##0.00);*("$"* "-"??*);*(@_)"
45 = "mm:ss"
46 = "[h]:mm:ss"
47 = "mm:ss.0"
48 = "##0.0E+0"
49 = "@"

And from index 164, there are your custom patterns

Comment: The Type "0 - general" did the trick for me, otherwise numbers were displayed as string in Excel, and the "green top-left triangle" appeared.

Answer (score 3):

To know the format string used by Excel without having to guess it: create an excel file, write a date in cell A1 and format it as you want. Then run the following lines:

```
FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("test.xlsx");
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(fileIn);
CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.getSheetAt(0).getRow(0).getCell(0).getCellStyle();
String styleString = cellStyle.getDataFormatString();
System.out.println(styleString);
```

Then copy-paste the resulting string, remove the backslashes (for example `d/m/yy\ h\.mm;@` becomes `d/m/yy h.mm;@`) and use it in the http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CreateDateCells code:

```
CellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
CreationHelper createHelper = wb.getCreationHelper();
cellStyle.setDataFormat(createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("d/m/yy h.mm;@"));
cell = row.createCell(1);
cell.setCellValue(new Date());
cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am writing my answer here because it may be helpful to other readers, who might have a slightly different requirement than the questioner here.

I prepare an .xlsx template; all the cells which will be populated with dates, are already formatted as date cells (using Excel).

I open the .xlsx template using Apache POI and then just write the date to the cell, and it works.

In the example below, cell A1 is already formatted from within Excel with the format `[$-409]mmm yyyy`, and the Java code is used only to populate the cell.

```
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("Path to .xlsx template"));
Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
Date date1=new Date();
Sheet xlsMainTable = (Sheet) wb.getSheetAt(0);
Row myRow= CellUtil.getRow(0, xlsMainTable);
CellUtil.getCell(myRow, 0).setCellValue(date1);
```

WHen the Excel is opened, the date is formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This code sample can be used to change date format. Here I want to change from yyyy-MM-dd to dd-MM-yyyy. Here `pos` is position of column.

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CreationHelper;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFColor;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFont;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

class Test{ 
public static void main( String[] args )
{
String input="D:\\somefolder\\somefile.xlsx";
String output="D:\\somefolder\\someoutfile.xlsx"
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(input));
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
Iterator<Row> iterator = sheet.iterator();
Cell cell = null;
Row row=null;
row=iterator.next();
int pos=5; // 5th column is date.
while(iterator.hasNext())
{
    row=iterator.next();

    cell=row.getCell(pos-1);
    //CellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
    XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = (XSSFCellStyle)cell.getCellStyle();
    CreationHelper createHelper = wb.getCreationHelper();
    cellStyle.setDataFormat(
        createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"));
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date d=null;
    try {
        d= sdf.parse(cell.getStringCellValue());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        d=null;
        e.printStackTrace();
        continue;
    }
    cell.setCellValue(d);
    cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
   }

file.close();
FileOutputStream outFile =new FileOutputStream(new File(output));
workbook.write(outFile);
workbook.close();
outFile.close();
}}
```