# How to write Date in Excel Sheet using Apachi POI

Tags: apache-poi

I'm using Apachi POI 3.9 to process excel sheet. I've set the cell value as "12/2/1990". But when i set the cell value as Java Date instance, it was not properly set. when i open the file i found cell's format has been changed to General. How Can i set Date values (MM/dd/yyyy)in a Cell as Excel Date ??

Comment: Did you try following the [Creating Date Cells Tutorial on the Apache POI website](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CreateDateCells)? If so, where did you get stuck? (Code might well help)

Comment: finally i was able to resolve the problem. I didn't set date format in properly. that was the root cause. Thanks

Comment: You can take look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794659/poi-how-do-i-set-cell-value-to-date-and-apply-default-excel-date-format