# POI - Date format dd-mmm-yy not recognized as a Excel format

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using POI-3.10.1 and Java 1.5 to generate excel files which contains date fields whose formats are
`dd-mmm-yy`.

> Eg: 24-Nov-15

This is the sample code :

```
Workbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook();
SXSSFSheet sheet = (SXSSFSheet) wb.createSheet(sheetName);

// Create date formatter
CellStyle dateCellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
DataFormat dataFormat = wb.createDataFormat();
short format = dataFormat.getFormat("dd-mmm-yy");
dateCellStyle.setDataFormat(format);

Row row = sheet.createRow(rowIndex);

Cell dateCell = row.createCell(columnIndex);
dateCell.setCellValue(dataValue);
dateCell.setCellStyle(dateCellStyle);
```

The problem is this, when I open and select a date field in the generated excel file in Windows, the format of the Cell is shown as `Custom`.

Following is the steps to recreate/get the issue in Windows:

1. **Select a date cell**

[image]

2. **Right click on the cell and select `Format Cells...` option**

[image]

3. **The opened window, the type of the cell is selected as Custom**, even though there is a matching type under the Date formats
   [image]

Really appreciate if any one can give/show directions or a solution to show the this `dd-mmm-yy` formatted dates under `Date` field styles.

Comment: See if this help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794659/poi-how-do-i-set-cell-value-to-date-and-apply-default-excel-date-format

Comment: @HelpingHands thank you for the reply, but it didn't help.

Comment: `dd-mmm-yy` is a custom date format though - the default date format changes the date/month order depending on locale, while yours always looks the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
short format = dataFormat.getFormat(DateFormatConverter.convert(Locale.ENGLISH, "dd-MMM-yy"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at my code for something similar I did a while back I'm creating date cells as numeric type. From what I recall this is how Excel represents dates internally (there is a date format, but no date "type").

From the [documentation for createCell](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#createCell(int)):

> The cell that is returned is a `Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK`. The type can be
>   changed either through calling `setCellValue` or `setCellType`.

You can also create a numeric cell using:

```
Cell dateCell = row.createCell(columnIndex, Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
```