# Issue while opening excel cells with Dates, After writing values with Apache POI Scala

Tags: scala, apache-poi

I am writing dates in rows in xlsx file with *Apache POI* scala.

It is writing in file and showing format as Custom date but values are not reflecting as **Custom date** until I am clicking double on that cell. After double click it is converting as custom date.

Can someone please tell me why this cell formatting is not reflecting on values. I have tried all ways available on stack overflow for formatting in apache POI.

```
            val cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
            val df = workbook.createDataFormat();
            cellStyle.setDataFormat(df.getFormat("MMM-yy"))
            cell.setCellValue(r)
            cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle)
```

[Excel value show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdzLD.png)

Comment: what is the type of `r`?

Comment: this answer did not help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/5794743/2750966

Comment: r is raw data formatted as Date.

Comment: No, I have tried this too, its only changing cell format as Date but data inside cell is reflecting only after double click.

Comment: try `val r = new java.util.Date()`

Comment: Thanks. Parsing r into Date worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For completion:

POI provides different `setCellValue`
 methods for different formats. See the [Java Docs](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#setCellValue-java.util.Date-).

Depending on the datatype you have POI will create the according Excel Cell Type.

So in your case you have the following possibilities:

```
setCellValue(java.util.Date value)
setCellValue(java.time.LocalDateTime value)
setCellValue(java.time.LocalDate value)
setCellValue(java.util.Calendar value)
```

So your `cell.setCellValue(r)` must be one of the above if you want a Date Cell.