# POI Excel date-time format dependent on region

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I would like dates to be formatted as date-times depending on the region.

Looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794659/how-do-i-set-cell-value-to-date-and-apply-default-excel-date-format) a date format of `14` can be used. This will make the format change depending on region. E.g. `d/m/yy` for UK while `m/d/yy` for US. This will only include the date and not time too.

Is it possible to do the same but to also include times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [this documentation](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/BuiltinFormats.html) you might want to use `0x16` (`22` as decimal) as key:

> `0x16, "m/d/yy h:mm"`

Comment: That looks like it. Is it possible to include seconds? I've been looking at the other formats from 3-8 and I'm not sure what they represent.

Comment: The list does not show a date time format with seconds. I guess you need to rely on the current locale and use the corresponding date time format.